# Getting a SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, qt

First time on stackoverflow.  I am trying to reproduce an example I have found on the internet for a custom frameless window with custom titlebar. Here is the website (I had to use google translate to be able to read it in English) http://qt.developpez.com/tutoriels/braindeadbzh/customwindow/

I am running ubuntu 16.04 using QT creator as my IDE.  I have the latest 64 bit version.

I have done 3.2 and before going on to 3.3 I am getting a SIGSEGV at the line where it says:
Delete m_Cache;

everything compiles bur when running it in debugger it comes out SIGSEGV.
I know this is an out of range error but not sure why.  Any suggestions or help would be most appreciated.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Most likely m_Cache is an invalid pointer (i.e. it is non-NULL but is pointing to a memory location that does not contain a valid C++ object that was previously allocated with the new operator).  One common cause for this is trying to delete the same object more than once.  Another common cause would be neglecting to initialize the pointer to a valid value (e.g. either NULL or an object allocated with new) before deleting it.

Comment: I briefly looked over that code – I bet the segfault would go away if you just initialized `m_Cache` to a null pointer: `QPixmap *m_Cache = nullptr;`

Comment: Use `valgrind`.

Comment: Thx Velkan that did the trick.  I still have alot to learn about using the IDE with all its tricks and aids but now I have a good practice point in trying to figure them out.

Answer (score 2):

`m_cache` needs to be initialized to NULL (nullptr if using C++11 and above) in the constructor, otherwise it will be left uninitialized, and the first time that `delete m_cache` line is reached it will try to delete a garbage address.
(note that calling delete on a NULL/nullptr pointer is valid and does nothing)

ps: en français dans le texte:

> Attention : pensez à initialiser à NULL le pointeur m_Cache dans le constructeur.

;)